# Any() linq query on XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am not able to use `Any()` on `XmlNodeList`. I have also used System.Linq and System.Xml.Linq namespaces as well. But still I'm not finding any such extension methods on `XmlNodeList`.

How I can use it??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that `XmlNodeList` only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`. The simplest way to use LINQ on it is to call `Cast`:

```
var query = nodeList.Cast<XmlNode>()
                    .Where(...)
                    ...;
```

Alternatively, ditch the old XML API and use LINQ to XML, which is a much nicer API in general *and* supports LINQ really nicely :)